# tcolorbox overflowing text when using parbox=false

Tags: tcolorbox, tufte, parskip, parbox

I have the problem that when I add `parbox=false` to the options of tcolorbox, the text within the box is not breaking properly. Do you have an idea what might be the issue?

Here is the code:

```tex
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]

%--------Examples-------------
\newtcbtheorem
  [use counter*=thm,number within=chapter,crefname={example}{examples},Crefname={Example}{Examples}]%
  {ex}
  {Example}
  {%
    before skip=10pt,after skip=10pt,
    left=0.2cm,right=0.2cm,top=0cm,
    toptitle=0.2cm,bottomtitle=0cm,
    breakable,
    toprule at break=0.2cm,
    sharp corners,
    colback=blue!10,
    coltitle=black,
    colframe=blue!10,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    parbox=false,
  }% options
  {ex}% prefix

\begin{document}

\begin{ex}{Test}{}
\Blindtext
\end{ex}

\end{document}
```

I am using the `parskip` package and want it to be applied to the contents of the tcolorbox too. That's why I want to set the `parbox` option to `false`.

With `parbox=false`:
[image: with parbox=false]

Without `parbox=false`:
[image: without parbox=false]

Comment: Please add the missing parts to your code, so we can copy and run it.

Comment: @MS-SPO I changed the code so that you can copy/paste and run it :)

Comment: Seems to be related to the default ragged text setting in `tufte-book` document class.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ thank you for your pointer! interestingly, adding the option `halign=flush left` (so `\raggedright` to every box) fixes things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `parbox=false`, a customized `\@parboxrestore` is used for that `tcolorbox`.

```tex
% default definition in latex2e kernel
% $ latexdef -s \@arrayparboxrestore
% latex.ltx, line 11974:
\def\@arrayparboxrestore{%
  \let\if@nobreak\iffalse
  \let\if@noskipsec\iffalse
  \let\par\@@par
  \let\-\@dischyph
  \let\'\@acci\let\`\@accii\let\=\@acciii
  \parindent\z@ \parskip\z@skip
  \everypar{}%
  \linewidth\hsize
  \@totalleftmargin\z@
  \leftskip\z@skip \rightskip\z@skip \@rightskip\z@skip
  \parfillskip\@flushglue
  \lineskip\normallineskip
  \lineskiplimit\normallineskiplimit
  \baselineskip\normalbaselineskip
  \sloppy}

% customized one
% tcolorbox.sty
\def\tcb@parbox@false@settings{%
  \linewidth\hsize%
  \@totalleftmargin\z@%
  \leftskip\z@skip%
  \rightskip\z@skip%
  \@rightskip\z@skip%
}

\def\tcb@parbox@use@false{%
  \def\@parboxrestore{%
    \tcb@parbox@false@settings%
    \let\@parboxrestore=\tcb@parboxrestore%
    }%
}
```

Among all those differences, the one relevant to OP's case is `\sloppy` (and the ragged text setting introduced by `tutfe-book` class), which is defined as

```tex
% $ latexdef -s \sloppy
% latex.ltx, line 13894:
\DeclareRobustCommand\sloppy{%
  \tolerance 9999%
  \emergencystretch 3em%
  \hfuzz .5\p@
  \vfuzz\hfuzz}
```

Hence inserting `\sopply` is a direct solution. For better result and since `tutfe-book` class has loaded and configured `ragged2e` package, `\justifying` would help.

As for where to pass these commands, the best choice is some `halign=<arbitrary alignment code>` option which is not yet supported by `tcolorbox`. As a workaround, you can put them in font options like `fontupper` and `fontlower`.

```tex
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\newcommand\test[1]{
  \begin{tcolorbox}[title=\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}, #1]
    \lipsum[2][1-6]
  \end{tcolorbox}
}

Base case
\test{parbox=true}
\test{parbox=false}

Simulate \verb|parbox=true|
\test{parbox=false, fontupper=\sloppy}

Try better
\test{parbox=false, fontupper=\justifying}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great answer, thank you!